# Why doesn't Illustrator automatically overprint 100% black?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, black, overprint

I am creating print PDFs from InDesign that contain Illustrator files. Most of these Illustrator files have black outlines used. When you create a fresh outline with 100% black, it's not set to overprint. And apparently Indesign doesn't give it the overprint attribute either even if "Overprint Black at 100%" is checked, because it's from an embedded file.

So, the print PDFs, in PDF/x-1a standard, have all the black strokes in knock-out mode when I check through the Output Preview.

Now, the only option left is for me to use the "overprint black" option from Edit Colours of Illustrator for hundreds of illustrations and then save and export fresh Indesign PDFs.

Shouldn't black automatically be set to overprint in these software?

What do the pros do in such situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Black* is a special swatch in InDesign. It can't be deleted and it can be set to *Overprint Black at 100%*. Sadly, this is not the case in Illustrator, where *Black* is just the name of a swatch.

Note that only the specific swatch *Black* can be set to overprint. If you manually make a *CMYK(0, 0, 0, 100)* swatch, it will knock-out instead.

When the Illustrator files are placed in InDesign the black lines are not recognized as *Black*, but *CMYK(0, 0, 0, 100)*.

Neither InDesign nor Illustrator should automatically overprint black in my opinion. What if you wanted the opposite? When placing object on top of each other in real life they normally cover each other (unless they are transparent). Setting black to overprint is  a special technical "trick" for print.

Now that you've made this mistake, you are probably not going to make it in the future, but what to do now?

I see only two solutions:

1. Do what you're doing: Open every single file and correct the error. It's tedious, but he upside is that your files are fixed for good.
2. Use some kind of pdf editing software on the final pdf. I use *Enfocus Pitstop Pro* at work. It's a plugin for *Acrobat Pro* which provides all sorts of editing capabilities. Maybe you have access to something similar?

Comment: +1 for Pitstop It's overall clunky but it's really wonderful for post PDF work to adjust colors and PMS issues.

Comment: 3. use a script to set the values.

Comment: Ya know the annoying thing.... InDesign *honors* blend modes for embedded images. Set something to `Multiply` in Illustrator (with nothing under it) and InDesign will honor that allow you to place content under the inked image and allow the mode to work. [SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G6Js.png) -- but yet they can't make Indesign overprint black regarding linked files. It's annoying. I do agree though, nothing should overprint by default.

Comment: Fortunately, you can record the overprint black menu item in an action. It appears to be one of those who remembers your dialog input instead of just producing the dialog. So, you can at least somewhat automate the process by batch processing all files and selecting shapes if needed to get the overprint. It it also appears that without any selection the action will stop, so make sure to put down a dummy rectangle filled with black first, then select same fill color.

Comment: @Scott, I never realized that! Good to know.

Comment: I actually just discovered this ability a month or two ago, Wolff :) Comes in *very handy* when placing isolated images with shadows. You can set only a shadow layer in Photoshop or Illustrator to `Multiply` and InDesign honors that when placing a .psd or .ai file.

Comment: @scott If I want to overprint black, InDesign does honour overprint settings from embedded Illustrator files. So, I can turn on overprinting for objects manually in AI, no need for changing blend modes to 'multiply'. However, this trick of doing it on shadows that you mentioned will be useful for me in the future. :) … It's interesting that you found the trick a month or two ago. In this field, no matter how experienced you are, there's always something new to learn. I was feeling bad that I ignored this overprint issue the past 3 years!

Comment: @LWTBP My point was.. Adobe can make InDesign see and honor blend modes across apps.. I don't know why they can't alter how plates are generated (overprinting) across apps. It seems silly to me that upon output InDesign can't merely realize "okay, that's black, overprint it" - regardless of whether it's a native object or a linked object. I mean black is black upon output.

Comment: @Scott **It seems silly to me that upon output InDesign can't merely realize "okay, that's black, overprint it"** That is exactly my thought!

Comment: @Scott While this is almost 5 years old, it's still something present, hence I'll explain a small bit (if other still wonder) about why overprinting is not something shared between apps. To put it in simple terms, honoring blend modes comes from from the fact that the apps uses the same source codes for said blend modes (it's a pixel-based process which is why it can result in some cut-down images in vector-based app like InDesign and Illustrator when exporting to PDF). Overprint, on the other hand, is handled differently in codes depending on how the elements are generated in the file.

Comment: (Following my previous comment) While Blend Mode is a post-process applied after the images and content are loaded, Overprint is an integrated, for the most part, process that is apply from the get go. Illustrator store the overprint details in its elements (a.k.a. form or drawings) while InDesign store it in its Block or groups attributes. If InDesign was using Illustrator method (per-element), each page would take a lot more storage space. A book that is like 250MB would take around 2GB. (Imagine how slow it would get.)

Answer (score -1):

A quick fix would be to set the illustrations to multiply

Comment: THis doe not actually make any difference in print. ITs still not overprint at print time.